# how to send information of number of records processed in certain time?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssis

I Have a sql job with x number of records in a file(it will load trough SSIS).

I have to send to mail to agent with number of records processed and number of records left.

The mail should be sent for every 10 minutes

How to handle it by sql server?

I tried to get the count from ssis package but the actual reusult should be done through sql server

Comment: Try using [sp_send_dbmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), this procedure give the possiblity to send mails via SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless you design your package for such things.

SSIS is instructed to ingest MyBigFile.csv How many lines are in MyBigFile?

You can't know until you've processed the whole file. Maybe it's a simple CSV with no embedded line endings and you can zip to the end and find out, it's 5380000 rows. Great. Now what?

You need to store that information somewhere (a table) so that you can inspect the value and compare that to the total number of rows sent to the destination component.

But wait, what if your source file is XML, or json, or has embedded line feeds in there? Now the number of rows in the source cannot be determined until you run the data through some processing step to interpret it. Why's that bad?

At a minimum, you'll have to double-read your source file. Say it's a billion rows of very wide data and it takes 20 minutes just to read and interpret the data before you even begin transforming and storing the data. Welp, you've now tacked on an additional 20 minutes to the processing time just to try figure out how many rows you're dealing with.

With all of those caveats out of the way, you now have an table that captures some metrics about the package execution. In my framework, I call it PackageControl and I've added `EstimatedSourceRows` to the definition.

```
CREATE TABLE ETL.PackageControl
(
    PackageControlSK int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL 
,   PackageName varchar(100) NOT NULL
,   PackageID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
,   ParentPackageID uniqueidentifier NULL
,   ExecutionID bigint NULL
,   StartTime datetime NOT NULL
,   StopTime datetime NULL
,   RowCountSource int NULL
,   RowCountInsert int NULL
,   RowCountUpdate int NULL
,   RowCountNoChange int NULL
,   RowCountDelete int NULL
,   RowCountError int NULL
-- I question whether this should be nullable
,   RowCountTableStart bigint NULL
,   RowCountTableStop bigint NULL

    -- Custom field for question 74797981 
,   EstimatedSourceRows bigint NULL

,   DurationSeconds AS (datediff(second,[StartTime],[StopTime]))
,   CONSTRAINT PK_ETL_PackageControl PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        PackageControlSK
    )
);
```

You'd then design your package as Execute SQL Task 1 -> Data Flow Task 2 -> Execute SQL Task 3 -> Data Flow Task 4 -> Execute SQL Task 5.

## Execute SQL Task 1

When any package runs, I insert into this table (via Execute SQL Task) and store the resulting identity value in my package.

```
INSERT INTO 
    ETL.PackageControl
(
    PackageName
,   PackageID
,   ParentPackageID
,   ExecutionID
,   StartTime
,   RowCountTableStart
)
SELECT
    @PackageName
,   @PackageId
,   @ParentPackageId
,   @ExecutionId
,   COALESCE(@StartTime, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
,   @RowCountTableStart;

SELECT
    SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS PackageControlSK;
```

At this point, you have made an entry into PackageControl and have an id value associated to an SSIS Variable. Let's assume it's `@[User::PackageControlSK]`

## Data Flow Task 2

This data flow will be your Source -> Row Count Component and I assume you'll populate an SSIS variable `@[User::EstimatedSourceRows]`

That should run as fast as your disk subsystem and IO channel allow

## Execute SQL Task 3

The previous data flow having completed, we now have a value in EstimatedSourceRows that we need to stick into our table

```
UPDATE PC
SET EstimatedSourceRows = @EstimatedSourceRows
FROM ETL.PackageControl AS PC
WHERE PC.PackageControlSK = @PackageControlSK;
```

At this point, we have stored the number of records in our source which we'll then use as the divisor to provide a completion percentage value in our email

## Data Flow Task 4

This is your actual data flow with all the associated logic in it. Do note that if you throw away source data rows, it may be the case that total rows processed will never equal EstimatedSourceRows. As an example, the source file has Customer data and date of birth is not provided. That row is rejected and sent to a manual cleanup process. Now we've "lost" a row.

The other thing to note, is that the value of an SSIS Variable cannot change during the execution of a data flow. I am capturing the number of rows Inserted but while that data flow is running, if I inspect the variable, it's going to be the value it was initialized to, likely zero.

## Execute SQL Task 5

This is the final step of the package, all processing is complete and I update PackageControl to write summary data. And yes, those various RowCounts are things I capture in my actual data flow because

```
-- Close out the execution.
UPDATE
    PC
SET
    StopTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  
,   RowCountInsert = @RowCountInsert
,   RowCountUpdate = @RowCountUpdate
,   RowCountNoChange = @RowCountNoChange
,   RowCountDelete = @RowCountDelete
,   RowCountError  = @RowCountError
,   RowCountTableStop = @RowCountTableStop
FROM  
    ETL.PackageControl AS PC
WHERE
    PC.PackageControlSK = @PackageControlSK;
```

## Testing, execution and making this all work

If we can't "see" how many rows have been processed from within the context of the package and you want to have an external observer watching progress, then you'll need to have a place that reports rows processed. And you'll be in luck because the SSISDB catalog has just that!

The column `ExecutionID` in PackageControl is the linchpin here. When a package runs, there is a System scoped variable,  `System::ServerExecutionID` you need to pass that variable along to the insert into PackageControl.

That value will allow you to associate "this run" to the metrics the SSISDB natively captures about a package run. That query is going to look something like this

```
-- Get a list of running packages and estimated completion percentages
SELECT
    PC.PackageName
,   PC.EstimatedSourceRows
,   D.TotalRowsProcessed
,   D.TotalRowsProcessed / (1.0 * NULLIF(PC.EstimatedSourceRows, 0)) AS PercentComplete
,   D.AsOf
FROM
    ETL.PackageControl AS PC
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT
        SUM(EDS.rows_sent) AS TotalRowsProcessed
    ,   MAX(EDS.created_time) AS AsOf
    FROM
        SSISDB.catalog.execution_data_statistics AS EDS
    WHERE
        -- TODO: you need to identify this value
        EDS.dataflow_path_id_string = 'Paths[OLE DB Source.OLE DB Source Output]'
        AND PC.ExecutionID =  EDS.execution_id
) AS D
WHERE PC.StopTime IS NULL;
```

The final thing you need to make this work is logging to execution_data_statistics which happens under the Verbose logging level - which is not the default.

[image]

You can probably accomplish this under a custom logging level but this is a very solid shove towards a turnkey solution.